# Исключение ModelValidationException при попытке сохранения изменений

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Пытаюсь использовать подход Code-First с EntityFramework 6.1.3. Создал модель, которая должна описывать следующее: тип File, который может содержать множество SEPropertyValue и Path. 
При попытке сохранить изменения выкидывается исключение: `Во время создания модели обнаружены ошибки проверки.
Root.ProjectName.DataModel.Type: : Для EntityType "Type" не определены ключи. Определите ключ для этого EntityType.
Types: EntityType: Набор EntitySet "Types" основан на типе "Type", в котором не определены ключи.`

Не могу "расшифровать" это сообщение, в каком моем типе ошибка? Ключи вроде все указаны?

Модель:

```
namespace Root.ProjectName.DataModel {

    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;

    public class AggregatorContext : DbContext {

        public AggregatorContext() : base("name=AggregatorContext") { }

        public virtual DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Path> Paths { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SEProperty> SEProperties { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SEPropertyValue> SEPropertyValues { get; set; }
}

public class File {

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public File() {
        this.SEProperties = new HashSet<SEPropertyValue>();
        this.Paths = new HashSet<Path>();
    }

    virtual public ICollection<SEPropertyValue> SEProperties { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Path> Paths { get; set; }

}

public class Path {

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullPath { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset ProcessingTime { get; set; }

    public Path() {
        this.Files = new HashSet<File>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class SEProperty {

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int InternalId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public SEProperty() {
        this.Values = new HashSet<SEPropertyValue>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<SEPropertyValue> Values { get; set; }

}

public class SEPropertyValue {

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual File File { get; set; }
    public virtual SEProperty SEProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: а где класс `Type`? это раз. во вторых не вижу Аннотации `[ComplexType]` для свойства `Type` в классе `SEProperty`. для случаев следования соглашениям аннотацию `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` можно опустить

Comment: @Bald так в этом и вопрос. Нет у меня такого класса.

Comment: для чего Вам это свойство в классе `SEProperty` ?

Comment: @Bald свойство нужно для сохранения типа свойства (Int, String, bool, etc.)

Comment: Вы этот [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) пытаетесь использовать в качестве поля в таблице? почему бы не создать свой класс который будет использоваться для определения *типа свойства*?

Comment: Проблема в том, что Type - это не примитивный тип и он не сконфигурирован, а класс, для хранения типа и значения я бы предложил использовать строки.... и причем 2 поля, в одном определить имя типа, в другом значение... Или же если значение может быть не примитивным типом а например class или struct, то вообще использовать сериализацию....

Comment: @kimaman2 помогло. Оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ пожалуйста. Можно добавить также замечания Bald.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `Type` - это не примитивный тип и он не сконфигурирован, а класс, для хранения типа и значения я бы предложил использовать строки.... и причем 2 поля, в одном определить имя типа, в другом значение... Или же если значение может быть не примитивным типом а например class или struct, то вообще использовать сериализацию....

Так же, как справедливо заметил @Bald, можно создать отдельный тип, с этими же двумя полями, но думаю это немного излишне, если оба эти поля будут обладать атрибутом `Required`, т.к. приведет к ненужному JOIN в запросе...